# How to access Azure Proxy API using client credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a on-prem server which hosts a API, and I have exposed the API using the Azure AD Application Proxy using the steps mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-add-on-premises-application

I am able to access the API via the proxy using OAuth 2.0 by getting authorization code from Azure AD, and then a token, specifying as resource the proxy URI.

Question is, how can I access the API without going through the OAuth 2.0 authorization flow?

I tried the client credential flow by creating another Web API App (App2) and given access to the proxy app. I am able to get the token using client credential flow using the steps below.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/token
    ?grant_type=client_credentials
    &client_id={clientId}
    &client_secret={secret}
    &resource={proxyurl}
```

When I use this token to access the proxy API, it says

When I tried with token (by authorization flow) I am able to access the proxy API,  but when I tried to access the proxy API using the token given to the App2, I think it should allow to access the API.

Current result is:

> InternalServerError:
>
> This corporate app can't be accessed right now.
>   Please try again later...
>
> Next Steps 
>   Client request encountered an internal server error.
>
> Quick Links 
>   Learn more about Application Proxy services 
>   Troubleshoot Application Proxy services

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean, could you make it clear?  For example, you use app2 to access api by using oauth 2.0 authentication flow?

Comment: How have you configured authentication in your on-premises app?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I am doing some tests so for now on prem app is just pass through. But if want to access from proxy it has to go through AAD auth (thats how I did setup). 

All I am looking is, I have configured azure proxy for onprem app, wanted to access from the background process, so looking for non user interactive authentication mechanism, If I understand correctly i.e client credential flow.